# QT Qtoolbar jiggles when switching different modes

Tags: qt

So I made this video to explain the situation:
Basically we have different modes in our software that loads different widgets (we using QT widgets). When you click on a different mode (with a mouse click) the Qtoolbar jiggles to the sides. it seems that it is some sort of redrawing issue from QT. Funny enough it seems that it is related to the clicking event, because if you switch the mode with a keyboard this doesn't happen.

https://youtu.be/MWqJ5kxzkoA

Comment: This is quite unclear to make an answer with confidence. I recently had similar issue and inserted widget->updateGeometry() for the widget that contains the layout after the new layout change applied and that fixed similar issue.

Comment: Thanks AlexanderVX, but I didn't understand your comment. I actually have that setting there. It seems that this is happening because of transition "animation", when you click an icon that is part of the ToolBar it "moves down" and when you release it goes back, this is triggering some sort of redrawing from QT so things shift right and left to "accommodate". Is there a way to turn off that transition or animation? I will try to make the widget larger and see if this will solve

Comment: I meant to insert updateGeometry() after your code triggers layout update. It helped me with similar issue. It seems that Qt is also not perfect as we are,